# Alias not working?

Tags: alias

The following query has no results (just an example):

```
SELECT  projekte.ID as projekt_id, 
(SELECT SUM(stunden) FROM stunden WHERE projekt_id=select(projekt_id) 
AND user_id=27) as stunden,
CONCAT('Test:', stunden) as buttons
FROM projekte_user 
INNER JOIN projekte ON projekte_user.projekt_id=projekte.ID 
WHERE projekte_user.user_id=27  AND projekte.aktiv=1
```

**First question:**

Is the passage `select(projekt_id)` ok, to refer the alias `projekt_id`?

**Second:**

Is the passage `CONCAT('Test:', stunden)` ok to refer the alias `stunden`?

Comment: Can you tag your question with the specific database your are using (postgres, Mysql, Oracle...) ?

Comment: If you have no results, try changing your where clause `WHERE projekte_user.user_id=27 AND projekte.aktiv=1`. For example, remove one or both of them to see if you have results so that you can see which one is too restrictive.

Comment: If i delete the where clause or not i get the fault message: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select(projekt_id) AND user_id=27) as stunden, CONCAT('Test:', stunden) as butt' at line 2

Comment: I am curious how you are selecting from a table called 'stunden' to then use the same name as an alias??  As requested, please advise the database you are working with as some of the syntax may be type sepcific